# Determine $a$ and $p$ such that $u(x)=|x|^{-a}\in W^{1,p}(B_1(0))$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

> Let $\Omega=B_1(0)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^N:|x|<1\}$ and let $u\in L^1(\Omega)$ such that $u(x)=|x|^{-a}$, with $0<a<N$. Determine $\nabla u$ as distributional derivative. Then determine $a$ and $p$ such that $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$.

Regarding the first part of the exercise, given $\phi\in\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$, we have: $$\begin{aligned}
\langle\nabla u,\phi\rangle &= -\langle u,\nabla\phi\rangle = -\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\int_{\Omega\setminus B_\varepsilon(0)}\frac1{|x|^a}\nabla\phi\,dx \\
&= \lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\left[\int_{\Omega\setminus B_\varepsilon(0)}\nabla\left(|x|^{-a}\right)\phi\,dx - \int_{\partial B_\varepsilon(0)}\frac1{|x|^a}\phi\nu\,d\sigma\right] \\
&= \lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\left[\int_{\Omega\setminus B_\varepsilon(0)} -a|x|^{-a-1}\frac x{|x|} \phi\,dx - \frac1{\varepsilon^a}\int_{\partial B_\varepsilon(0)}\phi\nu\,d\sigma\right] \\
&= \lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\left[\int_{\Omega\setminus B_\varepsilon(0)} -a|x|^{-a-2}x\phi\,dx - \frac1{\varepsilon^a}\int_{\partial B_\varepsilon(0)}\phi\nu\,d\sigma\right] \\
\end{aligned}$$

---

Regarding the last part of the exercise, we need $\nabla u\in L^p(\Omega)$ and that happens if $p(a+1)<N$, i.e. $a<\displaystyle\frac Np-1$.

For $a<N-1$ we also have that the second term in the limit vanishes for $\varepsilon\to0^+$, since: $$\left|\frac1{\varepsilon^a}\int_{\partial B_\varepsilon(0)}\phi\nu\,d\sigma\right| \le \frac{\lVert\phi\rVert_\infty}{\varepsilon^a}\mathcal{O}\left(\varepsilon^{N-1}\right) \to 0 \quad\text{if}\quad N-1-a>0\text{, i.e. }a<N-1.$$

So, my answer would be $a<\displaystyle\frac Np-1$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is correct, another approach is using polar coordinates
\begin{align}
\int_{B_1(0)} |\nabla u(x)|^pdx &= \int_{B_1(0)}  \left|-a\frac{x}{|x|^{a+2}}\right|^p dx \\
&= a^p \int_{B_1(0)} \frac{1}{|x|^{pa+p}} dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{S^{N-1}} \frac{1}{r^{pa+p}} r^{N-1}dSdr \\
&= \int_{0}^1 r^{N-1-pa-p}dr \int_{S^{N-1}} dS \\
&= Area(S^{N-1})  \int_{0}^1 r^{N-1-pa-p}dr
\end{align}
Hence, the integrand $\|\nabla u\|_{L^p(\Omega)}< \infty $ if only if  $N-1-pa-p>-1$ in other words $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ if only if $\frac{N}{p}-1>a.$